# What does "calcs" formula do in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I encountered an XLS file with this formula in some of its cells. I searched the web for information on the formula, but I couldn't find anything. Could you help?

The formula in question is:

```
=calcs!$E$31:$AH$31
```

I can't understand how it works.

Comment: Looks like there's a worksheet called `calcs`. Maybe a hidden one? This formula then is just specifying a range of cells on that worksheet.

Comment: You're right! I just found it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You must have downloaded this file: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/ctndirectdownload.aspx?AssetID=TC102930043&Application=XL,&Version=15&Result=2#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't find anything is that there's no such function. As noted in a comment, it looks like `calcs` is instead the name of a worksheet. You can tell by the exclamation mark after it, which is used when prepending a worksheet name to a cell (or range of cells). A function would require parentheses around its arguments, which the formula doesn't have.

Comment: I understand. As jozzas pointed out, 'calcs' turned out to be a hidden worksheet. Thanks for your help.